# How to find the Device Type,whether it a ip camera or pc with IP address in android

Tags: android, camera, ip

I am working on a project in which I have to find the device type,whether it is a ip address of camera or PC.I am getting the ip address of all the devices in a LAN. Please suggest me the way to found that..

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

If you have the IP address you should also be able to get the MAC address. The first part of the MAC address is identifying the manufacturer. Therefore if you know which manufacturer produce IP cameras you will be able to identify them with a high probability.

A second identificator could be specific open TCP ports.

Comment: NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address); is not working on Lan,i am getting null in "ni" object....please help me how to get that

Comment: There is AFAIK no Java API for working with MAC addresses. You have to include the binary command `arp` in your app and execute it via `Runtime.getRutime().exec(..)`